# Strange excel Combox behavior

Tags: excel

Want to ask about my Excel file.

I have added a Combo box in my Excel Sheet, when I click on the drop down arrow, another drop down arrow appears near it.
It only happens in 1 PC, when I try it on other PCs this problem doesn't appear... The problematic PC has bigger resolution than the other ones...
The Combo box is an ActiveX control

All Office products are up to date.

Someone of you have any idea what could be? Some size problems? Resolution problems? Has someone of you issued something like this?

Unfortunately I don't have a screenshot...

Comment: Is it an ActiveX Control? I've had similar issues with those before, which is why I switched to Form Controls only.

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't say that is and ActiveX control ty

Comment: So... are Form Controls an option or does it have to be ActiveX?

Comment: I was using the ActiveX controls because they have properties Tab where i can specify the ListFillRange... Otherwise in Form Controls I have to fill ComboBox through VBA

Comment: You don't have to fill forms controls with VBA, you can set a range by right-clicking and Format Control.